# How can I detect (or inventory) all DLLs that don't use ASLR?

Tags: memory, zero-day, aslr, internet-explorer

[Based on this IE zero day,](http://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2013/10/11/anatomy-of-an-exploit-ie-zero-day-part-1/) I'm interested in listing all DLLs in our systems that have been compiled to not work with ASLR.

Ideally, I'd like to analyze a static file and not load it into memory to detect if it's compiled without ASLR protections.

Lastly, once I have a list of files that are incompatible with ASLR, what can I do to prevent or control them from loading short of uninstalling it?

Answer (score 6):

If you just want to know if one DLL supports ASLR, then load it into [CFF Explorer](http://www.ntcore.com/exsuite.php), go to the Optional Header section, then click on the `DllCharacteristics` row. If "DLL can move" is checked, then it's ASLR-enabled, otherwise it's not.

If you want to do a lot of them, I would write a Python script that enumerates all DLLs in a target directory, then checks them using the [pefile](http://code.google.com/p/pefile/) module. This gives you access to all sorts of information, including the `DllCharacteristics` field of the PE header, which you can check to see if `IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_DYNAMIC_BASE` is set. That'll tell you whether it's ASLR-enabled or not.

In terms of preventing them from loading, there's not much you can do. However, you can use EMET to set Mandatory ASLR on a process to enforce that every DLL loaded gets ASLR enabled, regardless of whether it's set in the PE file or not.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to @Polynomial for that excellent `pefile` module suggestion. I threw together a quick python script to do this. There is probably room for improvements but it seems to work decently enough.

```
import argparse
import os
import pefile


class DllCharacteristics():
    def __init__(self):
        self.IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_TERMINAL_SERVER_AWARE = False
        self.IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_WDM_DRIVER = False
        self.IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_NO_BIND = False
        self.IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_NO_SEH = False
        self.IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_NO_ISOLATION = False
        self.IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_NX_COMPAT = False
        self.IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_FORCE_INTEGRITY = False
        self.IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_DYNAMIC_BASE = False


def get_dll_characteristics(path):
    foo = DllCharacteristics()

    pe = pefile.PE(path, fast_load=True)
    dll_characteristics = pe.OPTIONAL_HEADER.DllCharacteristics

    if dll_characteristics > 0:
        if dll_characteristics >= 32768:
            foo.IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_TERMINAL_SERVER_AWARE = True
            dll_characteristics -= 32768

        if dll_characteristics >= 8192:
            foo.IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_WDM_DRIVER = True
            dll_characteristics -= 8192

        if dll_characteristics == 2048 or dll_characteristics > 2080:
            foo.IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_NO_BIND = True
            dll_characteristics -= 2048

        if dll_characteristics == 1024 or dll_characteristics > 1056:
            foo.IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_NO_SEH = True
            dll_characteristics -= 1024

        if dll_characteristics == 512 or dll_characteristics > 544:
            foo.IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_NO_ISOLATION = True
            dll_characteristics -= 512

        if dll_characteristics == 256 or dll_characteristics > 288:
            foo.IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_NX_COMPAT = True
            dll_characteristics -= 256

        if dll_characteristics >= 128:
            foo.IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_FORCE_INTEGRITY = True
            dll_characteristics -= 128

        if dll_characteristics == 64:
            foo.IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_DYNAMIC_BASE = True
            dll_characteristics -= 64

    return foo


if __name__ == '__main__':

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('dir', help='Directory to scan')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    dep_enabled = []
    dep_disabled = []

    aslr_enabled = []
    aslr_disabled = []

    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(args.dir):
        for f in files:
            bar = get_dll_characteristics(os.path.join(root, f))

            if bar.IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_DYNAMIC_BASE:
                aslr_enabled.append(f)
            else:
                aslr_disabled.append(f)

            if bar.IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_NX_COMPAT:
                dep_enabled.append(f)
            else:
                dep_disabled.append(f)

    print "ASLR Enabled: "
    print "=============="
    for i in aslr_enabled:
        print i
    print ""

    print "ASLR Disabled: "
    print "==============="
    for i in aslr_disabled:
        print i
    print ""

    print "DEP Enabled: "
    print "============="
    for i in dep_enabled:
        print i
    print ""

    print "DEP Disabled: "
    print "=============="
    for i in dep_disabled:
        print i
    print ""
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. Note that you can use the `&` operator to test for flags. I'm also unclear as to what `dll_characteristics > 2080` et al. are supposed to do. Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

5 years later, I've modified the code provided by @Ayrx using `&` operator to test for flags as @avakar suggested. Now it works properly:

```
import argparse
import os
import pefile

class DllCharacteristics():
    def __init__(self):
        self.IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_TERMINAL_SERVER_AWARE = False
        self.IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_GUARD_CF = False
        self.IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_WDM_DRIVER = False
        self.IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_APPCONTAINER = False
        self.IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_NO_BIND = False
        self.IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_NO_SEH = False
        self.IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_NO_ISOLATION = False
        self.IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_NX_COMPAT = False
        self.IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_FORCE_INTEGRITY = False
        self.IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_DYNAMIC_BASE = False
        self.IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_HIGH_ENTROPY_VA = False

def has_flag(value, flag):
    return value & flag == flag

def get_dll_characteristics(path):
    dc = DllCharacteristics()

    pe = pefile.PE(path, fast_load=True)
    dll_characteristics = pe.OPTIONAL_HEADER.DllCharacteristics

    if dll_characteristics > 0:
        dc.IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_TERMINAL_SERVER_AWARE = has_flag(dll_characteristics, 0x8000)
        dc.IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_GUARD_CF = has_flag(dll_characteristics, 0x4000)
        dc.IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_WDM_DRIVER = has_flag(dll_characteristics, 0x2000)
        dc.IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_APPCONTAINER = has_flag(dll_characteristics, 0x1000)
        dc.IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_NO_BIND = has_flag(dll_characteristics, 0x0800)
        dc.IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_NO_SEH = has_flag(dll_characteristics, 0x0400)
        dc.IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_NO_ISOLATION = has_flag(dll_characteristics, 0x0200)
        dc.IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_NX_COMPAT = has_flag(dll_characteristics, 0x0100)
        dc.IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_FORCE_INTEGRITY = has_flag(dll_characteristics, 0x0080)
        dc.IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_DYNAMIC_BASE = has_flag(dll_characteristics, 0x0040)
        dc.IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_HIGH_ENTROPY_VA = has_flag(dll_characteristics, 0x0020)

    return dc


if __name__ == '__main__':

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('dir', help='Directory to scan')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    dep_enabled = []
    dep_disabled = []

    aslr_enabled = []
    aslr_disabled = []

    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(args.dir):
        for f in files:
            flags = get_dll_characteristics(os.path.join(root, f))

            if flags.IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_DYNAMIC_BASE:
                aslr_enabled.append(f)
            else:
                aslr_disabled.append(f)

            if flags.IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_NX_COMPAT:
                dep_enabled.append(f)
            else:
                dep_disabled.append(f)

    print "ASLR Enabled: "
    print "=============="
    for i in aslr_enabled:
        print i
    print ""

    print "ASLR Disabled: "
    print "==============="
    for i in aslr_disabled:
        print i
    print ""

    print "DEP Enabled: "
    print "============="
    for i in dep_enabled:
        print i
    print ""

    print "DEP Disabled: "
    print "=============="
    for i in dep_disabled:
        print i
    print ""
```